# Do any GUIs exist for running build automation files (rake, msbuild, nant)

Tags: msbuild, rake, build-automation, nant

Do any GUIs exists for processing and running rake, msbuild or nant files?

Although I don't mind working with the command line I still find that I occasionally have to delve into rake/msbuild files to find out exactly what a task/target does or what arguments they expect.

Ideally I'm looking for something that lets you only input valid arguments for the task/s you're running.

Comment: There's a popular UI for `MSBuild` called `Visual Studio`, you might have seen it ;-)

Comment: He does say running, and running msbuild inside of VS is a pain in the ****, however it does do intellisense for nant and msbuild which is reason enough to use though i guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is a GUI for MSBuild called [MSBuild Explorer](http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/)